# Design principles that prevent overcharging of batteries in older vehicles without undercharging

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, automotive, charging, alternator

This question is regarding older (10 to 30 years old) cars which did not have a smart solid-state or electronic charger built in. Basically, lead-acid batteries in such cars were (and in cheaper cars, still are) frequently charged by direct connection to the alternator B+ terminal. Almost without fail, these older alternator voltage regulators attempt to hold the alternator B+ voltage at some setpoint between 14.4V and 14.7V (e.g. would be Figure 3 here: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l9466.pdf).

14.x V is the correct charging voltage for a moderate or heavily discharged battery, which requires an ABSORPTION charging phase with constant voltage and declining current. However, once the battery has charged close to 100% of its capacity, the charging voltage would ideally be lowered to a FLOAT voltage ranging between 13.5V and 13.8V. If this were not done, and the voltage left at the higher 14.4V—14.7V range, the battery would be “overcharged” due to a high charging current. Since it is already fully charged, the excessive charging current cannot be stored, it is converted into excess heat, warming the battery, resulting in gassing or even boiling over if sustained.

Here are two links that explain this: Battery charger basics (https://chargetek.com/basic-information.html) and 12 Volt Charger Tutorial (http://www.chargingchargers.com/tutorials/12-volt-charger.php).

These older cars seem to disregard the BULK charging phase of batteries, which is a constant-current phase that precedes the ABSORPTION charging phase for heavily discharged batteries. I believe the BULK phase can be disregarded for the remainder of this question, since a heavily discharged battery could also be properly charged by directly entering the constant-voltage ABSORPTION phase, wherein the constant ABSORPTION voltage would be sufficiently higher than the discharged battery voltage to provide an adequate charging current. i.e. the risk of undercharging is low even if the BULK phase is skipped. The only major risk to skipping the BULK phase would be that a too-strong charging current could be provided in the case of an extremely-discharged battery, which should not happen in the normal course of events. So we can restrict our discussion to ABSORPTION and FLOAT charging with no loss of generality.

Now, the real question is thus: Can such a “constant-voltage” 14.x V directly-charged-by-alternator lead-acid automotive battery be *overcharged*? If the vehicle is driven on a reasonably long trip, beginning with a fairly full battery, it seems likely it would hit full capacity quickly and then begin to overcharge/overheat. Given many millions of cars used the scheme described with a 14.x setpoint voltage, why did they not suffer? Note that temperature-compensation and/or using a Sense wire to more accurately read the charging voltage at the battery B+ terminal does NOT seem to solve the basic problem. The key issue is that such charging systems did not have a “smart” or multi-stage scheme that detected battery-full and dropped down to the milder FLOAT voltage of 13.x V.

In order to avoid this situation, it would seem that the regulated output voltage of the alternator could be reduced to say 13.9 -- 14.1 Volts. This would help avoid overcharging, as it is closer to the proper FLOAT voltage of 13.5 -- 13.8V of most lead-acid batteries. But it would introduce the opposite problem of undercharging. When a battery is heavily depleted, 13.x V would not be enough to develop an adequately strong charging current, particularly during short trips. Also, I cannot find any voltage regulator ICs that specify a 13.x Volts setpoint, indicating that vehicle electrical engineers indeed favor a 14.x V setpoint to ensure adequate charging (with a consequent risk of overcharging).

Why was overcharging not a problem in the millions of cars that have 14.x V regulators on their alternators that are directly connected to the battery?

Comment: Many Cars over that age (30 years) likely did not have alternators but dynamos…

Comment: Going back a little further than 30 years, (and alternators go back quite a lot further) routine overcharging released H2 at one electrode and O2 at the other. However, routine maintenance included topping up the battery with distilled water. Problem solved. (Until the advent of modern "maintenance free" batteries. Always remember. "Maintenance Free" is marketing jargon for unmaintainable).

Comment: @SolarMike Ouch, you made me feel old. But I think automakers started putting alternators in cars about 60 years ago, not in the 1990s.

Comment: @SolarMike More like 60 years ago (1960s)